# Detecting Multiple Anagrams

Tags: ruby, algorithm, methods

I was wondering if anybody could provide me with some assistance on detecting multiple anagrams inside of one large array.

I know that I can do a basic check using something like:

```
x = "Red"
y = "der"

x.downcase.split("").sort == y.downcase.split("").sort
```

However, I need help with something a little more complex than that. What I currently have is a large array containing well over 10,000 words, and I'm looking for to find the cleanest way to iterate through the array and return all anagrams separated into different lists.

For example, let's pretend the array is:

```
["Red", "Blue", "uLeB", "der"]
```

It should return:

```
[["Red", "der"], ["Blue", "uLeB"]]
```

They don't have to be returned in an array -- I just need a way of separating them.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of comparing each word to every other word, you can group the entries via [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), using the same logic:

```
words = %w(Red Blue uLeB der)

words.group_by { |w| w.downcase.chars.sort }
#=> {
#  ["d", "e", "r"]      => ["Red", "der"],
#  ["b", "e", "l", "u"] => ["Blue", "uLeB"]
# }
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan - this was perfect. :)

Comment: I did not expect to read `chars` in 2017 from anybody speaking German :) `puts ["äo", "öa"].group_by { |w| w.chars.sort }` #⇒ `{["a", "o", "̈"]=>["äo", "öa"]}`.

Comment: @mudasobwa `chars` is fine, your NFD characters are messing everything up ;-) Quick fix: `w.unicode_normalize.chars.sort`

Comment: ...followed by `.values` to get the output specified.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another approach using Hash

```
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
array = ["Red", "Blue", "uLeB", "der"]
array.each {|e| h[e.downcase.split('').sort.join] << e }   

=> {"der"=>["Red", "der"], "belu"=>["Blue", "uLeB"]}
```

Comment: Why would you suggest this approach? It seems to me you've reinvented `group_by`.

Comment: Just another opinion, but yeah may be it should be a comment.. not an answer.

Comment: Besides reinventing `group_by`, this answer has a serious design flaw: it abuses `each` for reducing the enumerable. It _should be_ `array.each_with_object(Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }) { ... }` instead.